# Как сконвертировать видео для Win10

Tags: видео, ffmpeg, конвертация

Есть видео с записью экрана. Обычно конвертирую так и меня всё устраивает:

```
ffmpeg -i smth.flv -vcodec h264 -acodec copy -format avi smth.avi
```

Проблема в том, что кодек h264 не входит в стандартную установку Win10.

Как сконвертировать видео с сохранением хорошего качества в формат, который будет воспроизводиться Windows Media Player'ом на свежеустановленной Win10?

Попробовал такой вариант, но качество портится очень сильно:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i smth.flv -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec copy -format avi smth.avi
```

Comment: Откуда информация, что h264 не входит в стандартную установку? Сам Miscrosoft считает, что входит: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/supported-codecs

Comment: @Yaant, ну у меня файлы не воспроизводятся...